# Searching and Highlighting words in Richtextbox is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox rtbADB, I have to find the words which in richtextbox, which are either "SDM" or "SurfaceFlinger, and highlight( change fore color or change background color) them with any color. I am using the below code to do the same. There are two problems with my code:

1. While highlighting, it scrolls through the content of richtextbox , I want the highlight to happen without scrolling through the content.
2. The highlighting is very slow. I want it to happen as soon as function is called.

   ```
    public void HighLightKeyWords()
     {
           string keywords = @"SDM|SurfaceFlinger";
           MatchCollection keywordMatches = Regex.Matches(rtbADB.Text, keywords);
           foreach (Match m in keywordMatches)
           {
               //rtbADB.Select(m.Index, m.Length);
                 rtbADB.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                 rtbADB.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                 rtbADB.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
           }
     }
   ```

Comment: This procedure should not move the scrolling positon. If it does scroll with (exactly) the code you posted here and there's no other procedure in place that handles the scrolling or selection positions in any way, post the .Net Framework version you're using (or if there aren't any and you can, test it with .Net FW 4.7.2+). Slow, well, it can be slow. While the Regex can be quite fast, performing the selection and applying a color is not. You may assume a 1~2ms per matched keyword on a ~10Mb text file.

Comment: @Jimi, I am using Visual studio 2019, and the .Net FW is 4.7.2. In a file for 300 match of text, its taking 20 sec for scrolling through each match and highlighting.

Comment: Then this is not the real code and many more parts are missing. You need to post your actual code and any *operations* involved in this procedure.

Comment: @Jimi, I found out the problem, its because I am using custom Usercontrol for Richtextbox having line numbers, it has events, which are getting fired many times somehow, which is making my highlighting operation very slow. Please recommend me an efficient way to add line numbers to a richtextbox. Right now I am using below link to add line numbers.    https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/creating-line-numbers-for-richtextbox-in-c-sharp